# @Gauge from org.eclipse.microprofile.metrics throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, quarkus, metrics

I use the quarkus-smallrye-metrics to get some data about the performance of my app. 
Every metric from the microprofile works, except of the one that i need the most - Gauge. 
Here is the method:

```
@Gauge(name = "uploadFiles_Gauge", unit = MetricUnits.MILLISECONDS, absolute = true)
    public Response uploadFiles(@NotEmpty @QueryParam("fileIds") String fileIds, @QueryParam("tags") @DefaultValue("") String tags) {
        return Response.ok(mibService.uploadFiles(tags.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : Arrays.asList(tags.split(",")), Arrays.asList(fileIds.split(",")))).build();
    }
```

And the error:

```
2022-04-22 21:00:09,846 [WARN ] [io.smallrye.metrics] [vert.x-worker-thread-1] [] [] Unable to export metric uploadFiles_Gauge: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.interceptors.MetricsInterceptor.invokeMethod(MetricsInterceptor.java:92)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.interceptors.MetricsInterceptor.access$100(MetricsInterceptor.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.interceptors.MetricsInterceptor$ForwardingGauge.getValue(MetricsInterceptor.java:112)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.interceptors.MetricsInterceptor$ForwardingGauge.getValue(MetricsInterceptor.java:98)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.exporters.OpenMetricsExporter.createSimpleValueLine(OpenMetricsExporter.java:493)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.exporters.OpenMetricsExporter.exposeEntries(OpenMetricsExporter.java:193)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.exporters.OpenMetricsExporter.getEntriesForScope(OpenMetricsExporter.java:159)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.exporters.OpenMetricsExporter.exportAllScopes(OpenMetricsExporter.java:110)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.MetricsRequestHandler.handleRequest(MetricsRequestHandler.java:116)
    at io.smallrye.metrics.MetricsRequestHandler_ClientProxy.handleRequest(MetricsRequestHandler_ClientProxy.zig:239)
    at io.quarkus.smallrye.metrics.runtime.SmallRyeMetricsHandler.handle(SmallRyeMetricsHandler.java:36)
    at io.quarkus.smallrye.metrics.runtime.SmallRyeMetricsHandler.handle(SmallRyeMetricsHandler.java:18)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.BlockingHandlerDecorator.lambda$handle$0(BlockingHandlerDecorator.java:48)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

As you can see, there is some problem with the reflection which I can't solve. 
quarkus-smallrye-metrics version is 1.9.2, same for the quarkus and java 11 is used.

What I have using @SimplyTimed:
[@SimplyTimed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Bcb.png)

What I would like to achieve:
[@Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj6eU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid usage of a gauge. A gauge metric is a single number and has to be applied on methods that return a number, but your method returns a `Response`. I think you wanted to add `@Timed` instead, to track the time it takes to call that method.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. 
But what I want to achieve is a readable chart of the response time of an endpoint. 
Using @ Timed or @ SimplyTimed gets be incremental chart, like that (I pasted it into the post). Is there any way to make every single response 'seperately' seen on the chart?

Comment: I added those two charts in the post :)
If it can't be achieved from the code, maybe there is a way to present the data like that - some specific way of obtaining that in prometheus? Or maybe in grafana?

Comment: What you're describing, if I understand correctly, is basically time-series data (you keep each data point separately instead of aggregating them to create statistics). MicroProfile Metrics  doesn't support this approach (neither does Prometheus I think). And if there's a lot of requests, such chart won't be very useful. I'm not sure what exactly I would recommend if you really want this, probably some database suited for time-series data, like Cassandra (there's a Grafana plugin for it I think), but generally I would advise to go with the aggregated data instead of keeping each data point.